# Require purpose string for iOS "TestFlight"build

Tags: ios

I am using "react-native-webview" to render html on Android and iOS. I have created the application and ready to create build, On Android I have successfully created the debug-build but on iOS, we can generate the ipa file and unable to upload into "TestFlight". As we can see this plugin using "geolocation" in background to fetch current location of web page on mobile web view (I have checked other 3rd party libraries and SDK but not found). But in my application, i'm not using any kind of permission related to location just render the html on available in JSON string format.

> From App Store we are getting the Location related permission. The
>   following email we are getting:
>
> Dear Developer, We identified one or more issues with a recent
>   delivery for your app, "app-name". Please correct the following issues,
>   then upload again. "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your
>   app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user
>   data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a
>   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string
>   explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.
>   Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access
>   user data will be required to include a purpose string.If you're using
>   external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a
>   purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose
>   string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library
>   or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't
>   contain the APIs. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy)."
>   "Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File. Your app's code references
>   one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist
>   file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
>   app needs the data. Starting spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
>   App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose
>   string .**If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
>   APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
>   APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
>   developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
>   their code that doesn't contain the APIs**. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy)."
>   Best regards, The App Store Team

They require **Purpose String ** to publish our app in iOS "Info.plist".

If we use only this permission on Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not uses any location.</string>
```

Is it okay if this **plugin** using **geolocation** internally but my app not using any location related services?

Comment: If you are not using the geolocation. Can you remove the package?

Answer (score 0):

Check for updates in the `SDK` documentation because he might have updated new version after removing this permissions or some other workaround.Most libraries i used recently has  been  updated due to this permission issue.

Secondly you can check the `SDK` code and try to remove the permissions yourself because your app is not using this permission so it wont be a problem for you.

To search for permissions to be removed you can use below command to search all the occurrence of permissions inside code .

```
grep -R "your Permission name" .
```

Hope it works for you !

Comment: Related to iOS, which file i have delete.

Comment: which sdk are you using?

Comment: I am using the library "react-native-webview"

Comment: you can try one thing  add 
                '<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>'
               <string>This app does not uses any location.</string>   once and and try to upload .if it doesnt work then we can move on to some other solutions because i checked your library there is nothing to be removed.

Comment: But you can see according to App Store email response - Purpose string should be provided by library provider.

Comment: I think what they meant is that one of library you are using has used Location permissions. To overcome that you have to update your p.list .They never mentioned that the developer of the Library has to update p.list .They just told that if you don't want to add the string in p.list then you contact the developer and get that permission removed from library itself.you can try it once .If the problem remains the app store will again send these points.So , i think there is no harm in trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190900/discussion-between-abhinandan-sharma-and-sahadev).

Comment: Ok let me see, if I will get any error, i'll continue this query